# Bash read file line by line, split by tab, send to java application

Tags: java, bash

I want to read from a file line by line, then construct a args string and then use this string to start an java application.

The file test.txt contains for example this lines, columns are tab separated:

> abc def ghj kln
>
> asd ss fdf twe

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
while read k d a m s
do
    echo java -jar test.jar -k $k -d $d -a $a -m $m -s $s
done < test.txt
```

unfortunatly it does not work. bash output is broken:

> -k abc def ghj kln -d -a -m -s

Comment: What value do you actually want in `k` and `d` and so forth?? Are you trying to read 5 lines at a time from `test.txt` and store each line in a variable?  (Also, probably need to quote your variables where you're using them.)  In short, what is the desired output?

Comment: `IFS` is a *field* separator, not a *record* separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say the columns are tab separated, so you should use `\t` for `IFS` instead of `\n` which means newline:

```
IFS=$'\t'
```

(Assuming that each line of the input contains the values for `k`, `d`, `a`, `m`, `s` separated by tabs).

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change your **IFS** to separate on tabs `\t` rather then new line `\n`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\t' read k d a m s
do
    echo java -jar test.jar -k "$k" -d "$d" -a "$a" -m "$m" -s "$s"
done < test.txt
```